# Eclipse ADT Layout Editor: no Properties

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

I have an odd problem: my layout editor is broken. The buttons in the first menu bar are missing and i can't get any properties on the right side. Also, if i add a View in the XML directly, the layout won't be refreshed until i close the layout editor and open the xml again. I have found some discussions about missing properties, but this doesn't really help as the additional properties screen don't fix the other problems.

I have already reinstalled ADT - without success.

[Screenshot of a default layout without any custom views](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cea75.png)

Answer (score 1):

If other solutions don't work, it might be interesting to be a bit more drastic: set up a new workspace and re-import your android project.

If that doesn't work => reinstall eclipse?

Comment: it seems that the new ADT 22.6.2 has solved this issue. So, thanks for your effort, i have not tried your solution after it works now.